# Setting `Parse.setApplicationId` in a place other than AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, appdelegate

Good Evening,

According to the Parse Docs, `Parse.setApplicationId()` is called in AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Is this necessary? Is there any issue in calling this function in another place, such as my initial view controller?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that should be fine, but why not just try? Just make sure you don't call it multiple times.

Comment: Yeah i've had it in my app now for a few hours and no problems so far. Thanks! What happens if it is called multiple times? Ever tried that?

Comment: No, but I don't think it could result in anything positive :) the source is released though so we could look at what happens

Comment: That's right! Haven't even looked at the source. Thanks for the help my friend.